# Very strange behaviour of SKPhysics

Tags: objective-c, ipad, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I have this code

```
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
} else {
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}
```

[image]

I've captured this screenshot from my `-(void)didBeginContact:(nonnull SKPhysicsContact *)contact` method. I find it very confusing, because `2 & 3 == 2`, but `4 & 3 == 0`. As mentioned in docs,

> If either comparison results in a nonzero value, an SKPhysicsContact
>   object is created and passed to the physics world’s delegate.

I wonder how it is possible? Since second expression returns 0, why the delegate method is called?

Comment: The quote says _either_ comparison not both.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am not from an English-speaking country.